# How can the ROS 2 TurtleSim turtle icon be changed?

Tags: ros, ros2, design, turtlesim, turtlesim-node

In the turtlesim program used in many ROS 2 tutorials, there is a turtle icon that can be controlled. I would like to change this icon to be a different image that I have been provided, so that when I draw shapes with turtlesim it is with this custom icon. How can this be done?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* @Kaushal Bhanderi

This looks like a homework question, and on stack exchange, questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve/understand the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving/understanding it. Please edit your question to add this information and take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. For advice on how to write a good question, see the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37).

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I haven't tried to change the images of turtlesim, but you can try to build the ROS tutorials package from source ([ros_tutorials](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/tree/humble)) add add your custom image to `turtle_frame.cpp`. and maybe that way it works.